# Any Multivariant Testing available for Native Mobile Apps

Tags: android, ios, testing, multivariate-testing

So, I am trying to search for a multivariant testing option available for native mobile apps. I am not able to find any online. Been going through blogs and google and I could only find [Google Optimize](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/optimize/compare/) and also saw few others like [optimizely](https://www.optimizely.com/)

But when I go through those options I only see options for website (like add urls or domain) which doesn't work with native mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

I do know that Optimizely's Full Stack product will allow for experimentation testing for native applications, anything with an internet connection really. Here is their official documentation for [Swift SDK](https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/full-stack/docs/swift-sdk).